# RDLC and Row Groups

Tags: c#, visual-studio, rdlc

I have a requirement to "un-merge" row groups.

For example, adding Row Group to Names causes this;

---

Names | Age

Chris    | 27

| 28

---

I would like to use the Row Group functionality, but have it not merge every field for names like the following;

---

Names | Age

Chris    | 27

Chris    | 28

---

Is there a simple setting in visual studio I am missing? Or a tablix property I am over looking? Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your group properties window there is the option to determine what it groups on. I would suggest trying to add age as an additional column to group on. This should have the name repeat for different ages.

[image]